# gamma function for half integers

Tags: gamma-function

[image]

How can one prove the gamma function for positive half-integers?

Here is my attempt for $\frac{3}{2}$:
[image]

How do I solve the last integral?

Comment: Can you compute $\Gamma$ for any half-integer?  Then use the functional equation for $\Gamma$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$
\begin{align}
\Gamma(\alpha+1)
&=\int_0^\infty x^\alpha e^{-x}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=-\int_0^\infty x^\alpha\,\mathrm{d}e^{-x}\\
&=\alpha\int_0^\infty x^{\alpha-1}e^{-x}\,\mathrm{d}x\\[3pt]
&=\alpha\,\Gamma(\alpha)
\end{align}
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
\Gamma\left(\frac12\right)^2
&=\int_0^\infty x^{-1/2}e^{-x}\,\mathrm{d}x\int_0^\infty y^{-1/2}e^{-y}\,\mathrm{d}y\\
&=4\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\int_0^\infty e^{-y^2}\,\mathrm{d}y\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-y^2}\,\mathrm{d}y\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\left(x^2+y^2\right)} \,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\infty e^{-r^2}r\,\mathrm{d}r\,\mathrm{d}\theta\\
&=\frac12\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\infty e^{-r}\,\mathrm{d}r\,\mathrm{d}\theta\\[8pt]
&=\pi
\end{align}
$$