# Evaluate the integral $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{e^{-\lambda |x|}}{|x|^k}dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

How can I evaluate the following integral, for $\lambda >0$ and $0 \le k \le 1-\epsilon$, with $\epsilon>0$ arbitrarily small number?

> $$I = \int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{e^{-\lambda |x|}}{|x|^k}dx$$

Comment: Hint:$$\int_{\mathbb R}\frac{e^{-\lambda|x|}}{|x|^k}\ dx=2\int_0^\infty x^{-k}e^{-\lambda x}\ dx$$Let $u=\lambda x$ and the Gamma function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just exploit parity, the substitution $x=\frac{z}{\lambda}$ and the integral definition of the $\Gamma$ function.
 It turns out that

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{e^{-\lambda|x|}}{|x|^k}\,dx = \color{red}{2\lambda^{k-1}\Gamma(1-k)}$$
for any $\lambda>0$ and $k\in(0,1)$. If $1-k=\varepsilon$ is positive and close to zero, the given integral is $\approx\color{red}{ \frac{2}{\varepsilon \lambda^\varepsilon}}$, since the $\Gamma$ function has a pole with residue $1$ at the origin.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I'm not quite familiar with formulas involving the Gamma function. Would you mind writing down some additional details for your claims?

Comment: @Hideki: everything is pretty well-known: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function

Comment: Also, is are there closed formulas to compute the numerical value of the integral?

Comment: @Hideki: any CAS is able to compute $\Gamma(x)$ for some $x\in\mathbb{R}^+$ with an arbitrary degree of accuracy. It is enough to exploit Euler's or Weierstrass' products, for instance. Again, the best reference is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function.

Comment: @Hideki Note that $\Gamma(n+1)=n!$, and [see here for half integers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2283308/gamma-function-for-half-integers) and [see here for other rational values](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0403510v1.pdf).

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Thanks.

Comment: Also, what if I wanted to evaluate $$\sup_{k} 2\lambda^{k-1}\Gamma(1-k)?$$

Comment: @Hideki: the $\sup$ when $k$ ranges over ? Such quantity is clearly unbounded when $k\to 1^-$.

Comment: Over $[0,1-\epsilon]$, as in the statement of the original problem.

Comment: @Hideki: the supremum over $(0,1)$ is $+\infty$ as a straighforward consequence of the shown approximation, the supremum over $[0,1-\varepsilon]$ is the maximum achieved at the right endpoint.

Comment: That's right. Thanks a lot. Do you also happen to know what input should I give to Mathematica or SageMath  or Matlab to have a plot the value of the integral for various values of $0≤k<1$ and $λ>0$?

Comment: @Hideki: in Mathematica, $$ \text{Plot[Evaluate[Table[2*Gamma[1 - k]/(n/10)^(k - 1), {n, 10}]], {k, 0, 
  1}]}$$